# Zookeeper reconfigure command return `KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented`

Tags: apache-zookeeper

When running `reconfig -add server.5=125.23.63.123` in zkCLI.sh (Zookeeper 3.5.3-beta) I get `KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented`

I have fallowed the documentation from https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperReconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperReconfig.html

> Note: Starting with 3.5.3, the dynamic reconfiguration feature is disabled by default, and has to be explicitly turned on via reconfigEnabled configuration option.

I think you may need to turn it on via https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_advancedConfiguration